# EF and Async - Weird live scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm implementing async all over my cloud-based project.

I'm now trying to figure out why my `TransactionScope` keeps crashing randomly. The messages are "Cannot perform this operation because there are pending operations" or "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction" an other similar.
I say that it crashes randomly, because if you retry the operation, it works eventually...

At first I implemented the `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` overload... the fail ratio decreased.
Then I made the whole operation use the same `DbContext` (previous guys created a new one for each CRUD operation, like selecting a user? new context for you! now you want the sales of that user? let me get that using a new context! Create a new sale? Lets do that on this new context here... and so on...). fail ratio declined even further.
Then i decided to `await` as soon as possible (previously i was firing some queries at the start of the operation, and only waiting right before using the result). That significantly improved the fail ratio.

Now, I got a message in my logs that signaled a FK mismatch... Thats really weird because this is a very solid app and FK logic going wrong is a very basic mistake. Looking at the log, i see something like "Error for client **CLIENT_A**. Complete message: (bla bla bla) The conflict occurred in database **db_CLIENT_B**"!!!

In my multi-tenant app, each tenant has it's own database, so **CLIENT_A** should have problems only with **db_CLIENT_A**. We are very meticulous about this.

That is a really serious problem. That means that either unity container is giving the wrong instance of `DbContext` (it's configured for single instance per request) or there's a serious problem going on regarding the async/await and parallel and distinct operations... I think it could be mix, taking into account that DbContext is not thread-safe and neither is the Resolve, although it's getting called only once (resolve for DBContext happens very soon on the pipeline)

So my question is: What can i do to figure this out?

**PS**: ON the last 7 days, i have 5 logs for this. This might've happen more times (the switching) but if the other database has a compatible FK... well, i will here for that in a couple of days when managers start emitting financial reports...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by Unity. This happens when I call 'Resolve' within a async scope.