# MS Unity Container - Compatibility with async/await

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, inversion-of-control, unity-container

When using Unity's `PerRequestLifetimeManager`, is there a chance that when my app return from `await`, on a different thread than it was first created on but at the same time on a thread that was on hold by another web request, the resolution "fails" and delivers the wrong resolution?

I'm asking this because i'm seeing some rare, but very disturbing logs of EntityFramework operations failing because of FK mismatch, and the logs point that the thread context belongs to TENANT A, but the database in question belongs to TENANT B, which was conveniently using the app at the same time...

Comment: Did you construct a minimal reproducible code example?

Comment: The `PerRequestLifetimeManager` uses the current `HttpContext` to store the object. Therefore, you must make sure that the httpcontext flows properly. In ASP.NET, you need to set `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` to `true` in the configuration, and use `await` **without** `ConfigureAwait(false)`, to stay on the current synchronization context

Comment: @KevinGosse Thats looks very promising... after a few tests, overall stability and mysterious crashes reported on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460783/ef-and-async-weird-live-scenario have stopped completely...